# how to sum multiple values from firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have `carts` collection and it contains `CartItems` as document, `CartItems` have `quantity field` I want to SUM them, I wrote this code but the return type should be  `List<CartItem>` how I can change it to `Int` and return `totalQuantity` value

```
suspend fun getTotalQuantity(userID: String): Int {
    var totalQuantity = 0
    CartRepository.usersDocumentRef
        .document(userID)
        .collection("carts")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                task.result.toObjects(CartItem::class.java).forEach {
                    totalQuantity += it.quantity
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test it but it should do the job:

```
suspend fun getTotalQuantity(userID: String): Int {
    var totalQuantity = 0
    CartRepository.usersDocumentRef
        .document(userID)
        .collection("carts")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                for (i in task.result.documents) {
                  totalQuantity += i.toObject(CartItem::class.java)!!.quantity 
                }
                // print or use totalQuantity here
            }
        }
}
```